# how to make a search page that when you go to one of results and come back. you still have your previous parameters?

Tags: angular

I have a serarch page with a filter parameters bar.
There are search results in the page. user may goes to the more information page for one of shown result cases.

When the search page has been left, user may decides to continue searching again. So he need to go bac to the searching page.

I need a way so when the user clicks on my "go back" button sees the search page with exactly the parameters when he left it. I don't know where to save or pass it. can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Redux` for managing your state. Or, you could simply create a **singleton** storage class for filters and inject that in to your search component.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an injectable service that implements the BehaviorSubject to store state. Each time the app renders a component (the user goes back and forth with the search page) it subscribes to the BehaviorSubject, which emits that last value (the state). I recorded a video with a sample app here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYNEH_k0e_4